# What is the best equipment setup for the Cave of Seven Stars?

Tags: star-ocean-4

So I'm in the Cave of 7 stars, currently around level 100.

I don't require lots of XP or Fol really, as I have many hours of grinding for the rest of the trophies anyway, so I'm wondering what equipment would be best for here. Obviously I want to block as many statuses as possible as that is the largest cause of failures during battle.

What Synth's offer the best items for blocking statuses?